# Limit exceeded message is shown in google map API but I did only 300-500 hits

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know google allows nearly 1000 hits per day, but I did only 300-500 hits.
This is the response I got,

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Please suggest me a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting your QPS limit, try reducing you call frequency

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have reduced the QPS still the problem continues.